# Validate an XML using XSD schema that contains DTD declarations in C#

Tags: c#, validation, xsd, schema, dtd

I've been trying to validate an XML file using a hierarchy of XSD files, some of them containing dtd files. I managed to do it succesfully based on the schema referenced via schemaLocation in the XML file by setting the validation flags `ProcessInlineSchema` and `ProcessSchemaLocation`.

However, for my scenario I'll need to deliver the XSD files with the application I am building, so the schemaLocation should be ignored (as it will point to somewhere on the web). The XML files are standard.

I created a simple example to test my problem - I have the following files:

main.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ro:sopa:main" xmlns:main="ro:sopa:main" xmlns:inc="ro:sopa:inc" >
    <xs:import namespace="ro:sopa:inc" schemaLocation="included.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="test" type="main:testType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="testType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="test1" type="inc:testInc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

included.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema [
    <!ENTITY % inc.dtd SYSTEM "inc.dtd">
    %inc.dtd;
]>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ro:sopa:inc">
    <xs:simpleType name="testInc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="&test;"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

inc.dtd

```
<!ENTITY digit "[0-9]{1}">
<!ENTITY alnum "[A-Z]{1}">
<!ENTITY test "&alnum;-&digit;">
```

Sample XML file:

```
<main:test xsi:schemaLocation="ro:sopa:main D:\schemas\main.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:main="ro:sopa:main">
 <test1>A-4</test1>
</main:test>
```

If I validate against the schema pointed in the XML file directly, it works correctly:

```
List<string> report = new List<string>();
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(delegate(object snd, ValidationEventArgs e2)
{
    report.Add(e2.Message);
});

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings);

while (reader.Read());

reader.Close();
```

However, if I try to set an XmlSchemaSet manually, it will not work.

```
public static string schemaUrl = @"D:\schema\main.xsd";
public static string fileName = @"D:\somewhere\testProd1.xml";

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> report = new List<string>();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    settings.Schemas = ProvideSchemaSet(report);
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(delegate(object snd, ValidationEventArgs e2)
    {
        report.Add(e2.Message);
    });

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings);
    while (reader.Read()) ;
    reader.Close();
}

public static XmlSchemaSet ProvideSchemaSet(List<string> schemaLoadErrors)
{
    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    XmlReader schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(schemaUrl, settings);

    XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, delegate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        schemaLoadErrors.Add(e.Message);
    });

    schemas.Add(schema);
    schemaReader.Close();

    schemas.Compile();
    return schemas;
}
```

This will crash on schemas.Compile() saying that the object test1 does not exist. This only happens if I use the dtd - if I take the DTD out of the schema, it works correctly.

All I searched around on the internet was specifically about either XSD validation or about DTD validation - however I didn't find any solution for this. Any suggestions?

Note: Schemas and DTD I have to work with are standardised so I can not change them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-load the XSD, processing the DTD portion then removing it

```
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        xrs.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = false;
        xrs.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\xsd\included.xsd", xrs);

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(reader);
        Debug.WriteLine(xmldoc.OuterXml);
```

This would give you an XML document that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema[
    <!ENTITY % inc.dtd SYSTEM "inc.dtd">%inc.dtd;
]>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 BETA - Developer Bundle (Educational) 16.0.0.7863 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ro:sopa:inc">
    <xs:simpleType name="testInc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}-[0-9]{1}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

You could then remove the DocType (which probably messes up the XSD compile)

```
        foreach (var xmlDocType in xmldoc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlDocumentType>().ToArray())
            xmldoc.RemoveChild(xmlDocType);

        Debug.WriteLine(xmldoc.OuterXml);
```

Leaving you with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 BETA - Developer Bundle (Educational) 16.0.0.7863 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ro:sopa:inc">
    <xs:simpleType name="testInc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}-[0-9]{1}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Although its legal to embed a DTD in an XSD I think its a bad idea, it really throws a lot of validators and tools.